# Why is this completion handler skipping a for loop

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have this group of code, I only want to run: `self.performSegue` AFTER all of the for loops and all of the Firebase's asynchronous tasks have finished running:

```
    getFeaturedPost(withCompletion: startNext)

    func getFeaturedPost(withCompletion completion: () -> Void ) {
    print("Getting featured posts...")
    ref.child("featured").child("amount").observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
        self.numberOfPosts = snapshot.value as! Int

        print("There's \(self.numberOfPosts) posts avaliable.")

        for pos in 0..<self.numberOfPosts{
            print("Getting reference names for post: \(pos + 1)")
            self.ref.child("featured").child("post\(pos + 1)").observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
                let postID = (snapshot.value as? NSDictionary)?["postID"] as? String ?? ""
                let userOfPost = (snapshot.value as? NSDictionary)?["userOfPost"] as? String ?? ""
                self.customValues.append(("/users/public/\(userOfPost)/posts/\(postID)"))
            })
        }
    })
    print("Done! The posts are: \(customValues)")
    completion()
}

func startNext()
{
    getPostData(withCompletion: {
        print("Finished getting data, going to main screen.")
        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "showHome", sender: nil)
    })
}

func getPostData(withCompletion completion: () -> Void ) {
    print("Getting idividual post data, there are \(customValues.count) posts")
    for i in 0..<customValues.count {
        print("Currently on post: \(i)")
        let encodedURL = (customValues[i] + "/postURL")
        ref.child(encodedURL).observe(.value, with: { (snapshot) in
            if let newURL = snapshot.value as? String{
                print("Sending \(newURL) to DemoSource Class")
                DemoSource.shared.add(urlString: newURL)
            }
        })
    }
    completion()
}
```

Yet the `startNext()` function (which goes to the next view) is executed before `getFeaturedPost`'s starts it's for loop where it prints what post it'c currently at. By the end when I send the data to the demosource class with `DemoSource.shared.add(urlString: newURL)` the `newURL` is nil, I have a console log which shows you the order of the print statements of each function:

```
Getting featured posts...
Done! The posts are: []
Getting idividual post data, there are 0 posts
Finished getting data, going to main screen. // This line should be printed last meaning this function is being executed too early
There's 2 posts avaliable.
Getting reference names for post: 1 // These two lines should be called before the line 'Finished getting data'
Getting reference names for post: 2
```

Comment: The `print(Done` line and the `completion()` call are executed immediately. The database requests return the data much later. With asynchronous tasks in a loop you need `DispatchGroup`

Comment: @vadian I thought as much, could you point out where I should add the dispatchGroups as I'm aware there might be more than one place to add them as I do two firebase queries.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The usage of `DispatchGroup` is very easy. It's a kind of a counter. `enter` increments the counter, `leave` decrements it. If the counter reaches `0` the closure in `notify` is executed.

- In the loop before the asynchronous block call `enter`.
- Inside the asynchronous block at the end call `leave`.
- After the loop call `notify`.

  ```
  func getFeaturedPost(withCompletion completion: @escaping () -> Void ) {
      print("Getting featured posts...")
      ref.child("featured").child("amount").observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
          self.numberOfPosts = snapshot.value as! Int

          print("There's \(self.numberOfPosts) posts avaliable.")
          let group = DispatchGroup()
          for pos in 0..<self.numberOfPosts{
              group.enter()
              print("Getting reference names for post: \(pos + 1)")
              self.ref.child("featured").child("post\(pos + 1)").observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
                  if let post = snapshot.value as? [String:Any] {
                      let postID = post["postID"] as? String ?? ""
                      let userOfPost = post["userOfPost"] as? String ?? ""
                      self.customValues.append(("/users/public/\(userOfPost)/posts/\(postID)"))
                  }
                  group.leave()
              })
          }
          group.notify(queue: .main) {
              print("Done! The posts are: \(customValues)")
              completion()
          }
      })
  }
  ```

Implement a group accordingly in the other method.

Side note: Don't use `NS...` collection types in Swift.

Comment: great Answer sir :)

Comment: @jawadAli if answer is great, then upvote :) **Comments are used to ask for clarification or to point out problems in the post.**

Comment: There is two errors when I use it `Escaping closure captures non-escaping parameter 'completion'` Will I need an @escaping?

Answer (score 0):

> **DispatchGroup**
>
> Groups allow you to aggregate a set of tasks and synchronize behaviors
> on the group. You attach multiple work items to a group and schedule
> them for asynchronous execution on the same queue or different queues.
> When all work items finish executing, the group executes its
> completion handler. You can also wait synchronously for all tasks in
> the group to finish executing. [Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/dispatch/dispatchgroup)

You can edit your methods using DispatchGroup

```
 func getFeaturedPost(withCompletion completion: @escaping() -> Void ) {
      let group = DispatchGroup() // create group
        print("Getting featured posts...")
         group.enter() // enter group
        ref.child("featured").child("amount").observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
            self.numberOfPosts = snapshot.value as! Int
    
            print("There's \(self.numberOfPosts) posts avaliable.")
    
            for pos in 0..<self.numberOfPosts{
                  group.enter() // enter group
                print("Getting reference names for post: \(pos + 1)")
                self.ref.child("featured").child("post\(pos + 1)").observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
                    let postID = (snapshot.value as? NSDictionary)?["postID"] as? String ?? ""
                    let userOfPost = (snapshot.value as? NSDictionary)?["userOfPost"] as? String ?? ""
                    self.customValues.append(("/users/public/\(userOfPost)/posts/\(postID)"))
                     group.leave()
                })
            }
                group.leave() // 
        })
        print("Done! The posts are: \(customValues)")
        
    }
    group.notify(queue: .main, execute: { // executed after all async calls in for loop finish
        print("done with all async calls")
        // do stuff
        completion()
    })

func getPostData(withCompletion completion:@escaping () -> Void ) {
    print("Getting idividual post data, there are \(customValues.count) posts")
let group = DispatchGroup() // create group
    for i in 0..<customValues.count {
group.enter()
        print("Currently on post: \(i)")
        let encodedURL = (customValues[i] + "/postURL")
        ref.child(encodedURL).observe(.value, with: { (snapshot) in

            if let newURL = snapshot.value as? String{
                print("Sending \(newURL) to DemoSource Class")
                DemoSource.shared.add(urlString: newURL)
            }
             group.leave()
        })
    }
    group.notify(queue: .main, execute: { // executed after all async calls in for loop finish
  
            completion()
        })
}
```